# Lazy loading angular module stuck in queue for some time

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, angular-module

Hi I am loading the angular modules through routes (lazy loading module). Most of time it loads instantly but very rarely it take much time to load. When i see the timing section of chrome it say around 15 seconds in queue. Screen shot is attached here. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code screeshots. Specially of how your modules is laid out. and the routes etc. Without looking at the code can't really say. Share that and secondly does same happen when you generate production file, does it have same behavior live or just locally?

Comment: are you using JIT mode for your angular app. i am 90% sure that you do and that is the reason. if you try to measure page startup performance, you will see that those 15 seconds are filled with yellow javascript CPU load

Comment: other 10% chance is during these 15 seconds you download other resources. check network tab without filters to confirm if that is true

Comment: This is intermittent issue when i do ng serve, I hardly saw this issue 2-4 times. I haven't see in production but not sure if any users